# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError, not a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, typeerror, factory-pattern

I went though all the posts here related to this topic, but couldn't find a working solution. May be something very different in my code.

File 1, RequestFactory.js

```
function requestFactory() {
    this.createRequest = function (reportId) {
      var request;
      request = new xyzRequestManager.XyzRequest();
      return request;
    } 
    return {
      RequestFactory: requestFactory
    } 
 }
```

File 2,request.js

```
function loadData() {
  var request = requestFactory.createRequest(id);
  request.loadReport(report);
}
```

File 3, xyzRequestManager.js

```
function () {
 var xyzRequest = function() {
   this.loadReport = function(report) { --some data--}
 }
 return {
   XyzRequest: xyzRequest
 }
}
```

So the call starts from file2, i create the request object by calling requestFactory. There are bunch of other functions written in file 3, which gets called from file 1 in similar fashion, request factory object, and make call to the function.

This gives error as,

```
Uncaught TypeError: xyzRequestManager.XyzRequest is not a constructor
```

I have wasted hours on this, and still no clue what or where am I wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `xyzRequest !== XyzRequest`.

Comment: Your `requestFactory` function adds a `createRequest` method to the global object and not to the `requestFactory` function. `requestFactory.createRequest` is `undefined`. That code has many issues. JavaScript is case-sensitive!

Comment: This would appear not to be your real code, not least because the `xyzRequestManager.js` shown would fail with a syntax error, and the code shown will produce a *different* error from that in the question (see Vohuman's comment). Create an actual [mcve] and show how you're loading the files such that they can refer to each other's contents.

Comment: Variable name and function name cannot be the same

Answer (score 1):

You're returning an object with a property called `XyzRequest`, not `xyzRequest`, see the `***` comment:

```
// Note: This is verbatim from the question other than this comment and
// the *** comment below.. It's not valid syntax on its own (the function
// would need a name), but I assume it's an excerpt from something larger.
function () {
 var xyzRequest = function() {
   this.loadReport = function(report) { --some data--}
 }
 return {
   XyzRequest: xyzRequest     // ***
 }
}
```

So to use it, you need that capital `X`:

```
request = new xyzRequestManager.XyzRequest();
// -----------------------------^
```

Comment: updated, and still the same issue. I tried with same name, different name, different casing even !! But still the same error.